# Unexpected result inside a Nested Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

```js
let conditon = false

const test = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
    if (0 !== test[j]) {
      conditon = true;
       break;
    }else{
      conditon = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(conditon)
}
```

In this loop it console.log true but it should print false when it finds 0 in an array

Comment: you are never setting condition back to false, when it finds first non 0 element condition will always be true, try setting condition back to false before the if statement

Comment: `for (let j = 0; j < test.length; j++) { console.log(0 !== test[j]) }`

Comment: did not work sir https://codepen.io/ranjan-raj-shrestha/pen/gOLNQzr?editors=1111

Comment: You still are testing the last element only! Everything before will be overwritten because you didn't change it the proposed way

Comment: What should be done if I want result

Comment: @RanjanRajShrestha https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707748/295783

Comment: @RanjanRajShrestha Your current code after the edit makes it break out of the loop at the first iteration, every time. It never even checks the rest of the elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are continuously setting `condition` to true, because e.g. `0 !== 2` evaluates to true. This is the case for every element, except 0. `0 !== 0` which evaluates to false. You need to put an else check in there and set `condition` to false, then break out so that it doesn't continue and override your value again by setting `condition` back to true for the next iterations.

```js
let condition = false;

const test = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
    if (0 !== test[j]) {
      conditon = true;
    } else {
      conditon = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(conditon)

  // Comment this part out if you want it to continue looping without immediately stopping.
  // Otherwise the loop ends once it hits 0.
  if(!condition)
    break;
}
```

This is not the best way to do this, mind you... I'm just providing you an example on why your code works the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version, which you can examine to see how it works, and which you can use as a template for a more complicated version if desired.

```js
let condition;
const nums = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  for (let num of nums) {
    condition = (num !== 0);
    console.log(num, condition);
  }
  console.log("\n--end of outer loop--\n\n");
}
```

---

**Edit**:
From your comment, I gleaned that after each trip through the outer loop, you want to report if any value in the array was zero. If this is what you're looking for, you'd do something like this:

```js
    const nums = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      let noZerosFound = true;
      console.log("checking: " + nums);
      for (let num of nums) {
        if(num === 0){
          noZerosFound = false;
          // Can include a `break` statement here for better performance
        }
      }
      console.log("noZerosFound: " + noZerosFound);
      console.log("\n");
    }
```

---

And JavaScript arrays also provide some useful **built-in methods** for this kind of situation. So if you want, you could simply do:

```js
        const nums = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
          console.log("checking: " + nums);

          // Applies the function `(num) => num !== 0` to each element of `nums`. 
          //   If the result is true for every element, returns true.  
          //   Otherwise, returns false. 
          const noZerosFound = nums.every( (num) => num !== 0);

          console.log("noZerosFound: " + noZerosFound);
          console.log("\n");
        }
```

See [the `.every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on MDN for further explanation.

Comment: I did this inner loop but I want same result outside of inner loop what technique should I follow  Cause I am working in a small project where I need the final result of the inner loop and send the condition to the outer loop on completion of each outer loop iteration

Comment: You can just log the value of `condition` after each time through the outer loop (instead of logging "end of outer loop") -- but be aware that the value will always be `true` by this point, becuase the condition gets tested for each value in the inner loop (including the last value, `7`, which is obviously not equal to zero.)

Comment: Are you trying to keep it at `false` if it finds a zero anywhere in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here. Let me introduce this way as an extra answer.

```js
const test = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(!test.includes(0));

const test2 = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(!test2.includes(0));
```

### .includes()

```
array.includes(<value>)
```

- `.includes()` returns `true` if a given value is in an array, `false` if not.
- **`!test.includes(0)`** returns `true` if `0` is NOT in `test`. `false` if `0` IS in `test`.